# How to get Jenkins build job duration

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

Is it possible to get Jenkins build duration using scripts or using some inbuilt functionality. I tried with `${BUILD_DURATION}` but it didn't work.

[image: Build duration displayed in Jenkins UI]

Can anyone please suggest?

Comment: I am trying for DSL jobs

Comment: I am not sure but maybe this same help - [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40022313/how-to-display-the-time-it-took-to-run-a-build-in-jenkins)

Answer (score 13):

Here are a couple of options:

**RESTFUL API**

Use a language of your choice to consume Jenkins Restful API to get the json for the build and deserialise.

**DECLARATIVE PIPELINE**

Use `${currentBuild.durationString}`.

The currentBuild object exposes a number of relevant attributes:

```
timeInMillis: 
    time since the epoch when the build was scheduled

startTimeInMillis
    time since the epoch when the build started running

duration
    duration of the build in milliseconds

durationString
    a human-readable representation of the build duration
```

Navigate to `https://<your-jenkins-instance>/pipeline-syntax/globals#currentBuild` for the complete list.

Comment: could you please elaborate on Restful API?
I was looking for freestyle DSL jobs

Comment: Many pages in Jenkins expose json if you append /api/json.  It is up to you to programmatically hit the appropriate endpoint and, consume and deserialise the json.

Comment: Hi @Siddarth, Would appreciate if you could accept this answer. Let me know if you need anymore info.

Comment: could you please provide any reference page?

Comment: almost any page in Jenkins just add /api/json

Comment: i tried getting the duration with json API in a post build task action like this "duration=$(curl -g -u login:token--silent "$BUILD_URL/api/json?pretty=true&tree=duration" | jq -r '.duration')" but i always get 0

Answer (score 2):

I am Jenkins beginner & below **Groovy script** is an easy approach;

```
def item = Jenkins.instance.getItem("<Job_name>")

def last_job_duration = item.getLastBuild().getDurationString()

println last_job_duration
```

Comment: i tried getting the duration with json API in a post build task action like this "duration=$(curl -g -u login:token--silent "$BUILD_URL/api/json?pretty=true&tree=duration" | jq -r '.duration')" but i always get 0